# Prolog remove items from a list

Tags: prolog

I know how to delete an items from a normal list like this one `[1,2,3,4]`, but how can I delete the first number from a list that looks like this:

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)....]
```

to give:

```
[2,4,6,8,...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this work?(I didn't test this code):

```
maplist(nth1(1),[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]],Ret).
```

or

```
maplist(arg(1),[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)],Ret).
```

Comment: oh sorry , use 'nth1'